# Laravel Homestead PHP not being rendered

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I just had a fresh install of Homestead and did everything exactly on the tutorial.
The folder mapping is as follow:

```
folders:
- map: D:/Homestead/guidev-cms
  to: /home/vagrant/guidev-cms

sites:
- map: cms.app
  to: /home/vagrant/guidev-cms/public
```

When I browse cms.app. Only the HTML gets rendered. The PHP is just being ignored.
Anybody having the same issue, or know a possible solution?

For example when I do a `echo "Test";` this wont show. Just everything between the `<?php ?>` are not being rendered. Although it is a `.php` file..

Comment: Re: The PHP is just being ignored, could you be more specific?  Is the PHP code showing up un-executed?  Are areas of the page that should have HTML generated by PHP just blank?

Comment: Ive added a example in my question.

Comment: When you view the source (not in the browser, and not in the chrome debugger, but from the view source menu) of your page does it show `<?php echo "Test" ?>`?  Or does it show a nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it was another thing. Cause I upgraded to Laravel 5.0. I forgot the include a `Form` serviceprovider. It's all working now, thx though.

Comment: Hi, I've got the same issue. The html renders but a simple php echo test renders nothing. I can't see why I should need any Laravel script yet (I'm not sure what the Form service provider stuff you mention is), all I'm doing is trying to do is echo some simple php in an index page as a test. Can you help?

Comment: ^ never mind, it was a simple overlook. I was using '<?' in my code instead of the full '<?php' syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with a different cause.  I had created the php file using Notepad++, and incorrectly saved it as "index.php.txt".  Once I noticed the problem and corrected the filename to index.php, everything worked fine.